# Best way to plot clustered network

Tags: python, pandas, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx

I Have a Huge data-set with more than million nodes, edges and communities. What is the best way to plot a network graph that shows clusters.

I did try [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) using but that does not seem to provide what I am looking for.

I am trying to find a better way may be programming in Python to plot a cluster graph.

Any suggestions are appreciated... Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you _really_ want to plot it? If the network has good modularity, you can extract the communities and build an induced graph, where communities are represented as nodes.

Comment: @DYZ I do have to plot the graph possibly better visible way. As mentioned I have huge dataset (size more than 2 gb)

Comment: Plotting huge networks is never an enlightening way to learn about them. What you really is only a hairball. As @DYZ said, it is better to plot an induced graph.

Comment: @Peaceful I agree with your point.. But need to plot the large clustering for an result purpose. Small level I could get using Cytoscape. To study and learn but for large dataset that displays a giant ball of dots.

Comment: I suggest graph-tool as the best shot. Networkx is rather a bad choice for drawing graphs. I still disagree with the argument that you need to plot the whole graph for any purpose whatsoever.

Comment: @Peaceful Sure thanks I am looking into "Gephi" tool and yes ofcoure I am trying to slash down .. But l am not sure what will be the best way ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You flagged your post with networkx. Did you try the in-built drawing functions with Matplotlib? See the documentation [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/drawing.html). However, even there they strongly recommend specialized software such as Cytoscape, Gephi or Graphviz.

Comment: I am open to every suggestion as I may not see in right direction. I used included Networkx coz I was trying to work with networkx after Cytoscape could not help. I will check the other tools as well .. Thanks for the suggestions..

Comment: Networkx is definitely a great tool for network and graph analyses. Since you are interested in clusters in your network, you can make use of `networkx.connected_components` and `networkx.subgraph`.

Comment: Networkx will fail to plot more than million nodes. He is just not getting the point. I suggest looking at the graph with 10000 vertices only to see what I am talking about.